# Applying CSS 'fadeInDown' animation on a div stops jQuery 'Scroll to Fade' working on the same div

Tags: jquery, html, css, animation

Does anyone know why applying CSS 'fadeInDown' animation on a div would stop jQuery 'Scroll to Fade' working on the same div?

I'm working on an interactive infographic and want a piece of text to fade down using CSS fadeInDown but also fade out on scroll using. The jQuery fade on scroll applies fine on the div until I add the CSS 'fadeInDown'.  This is the link to the section I'm having problems with http://itssjp.co.uk/infographic/

Comment: Are they cancelling each other out?

Comment: Yeah @AndyHolmes each work fine on their own, but when both are in together the CSS animation takes priority over the jQuery, looking both to work.

Comment: Have you tried using jQuery WayPoints? They might be able to help you do the fade on scroll thing, which means that your css will remain intact

Comment: I plan on using WayPoints to fade in the content, although I'm unsure of how how to use WayPoints to fade in down the div in the head section

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like the opacities stack if you modify the opacity properties of the child elements rather than the animated parent.

```
$(window).bind('scroll', function(){
    var offset = $(document).scrollTop()
        ,opacity=0
    ;
    if( offset<=fadeStart ){
        opacity=1;
    }else if( offset<=fadeUntil ){
        opacity=1-offset/fadeUntil;
    console.log(opacity);
    }
    headintro.children().css('opacity',opacity);
});
```